# How to check a value in a list value range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a value to check in the list range

Example:

```
    recipies = int(input("enter:"))
print(recipies)
interval =[]
for i in range(recipies):
    x = (input().split())
    interval.append(x)
print(interval)
agroup =int(input("enter:"))
print(agroup)
qali = []
for i in range(agroup):
    x = (input().split())
    qali.append(x)
print(qali)
for cmp in qali:
    toa = cmp[1:]

Input:
4
1 4
3 10
2 6
5 8
3
1 5
2 2 6
3 1 10 9

Output:
3
4
2
```

Here i want to check weather the value of toa available in the interval if available i want to print how many times that value available in the given intervals,same way i want to check values in quali(list)

Comment: Note that `list` is not a great variable name; it masks the bulit-in type. I changed it to `ranges` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following list comprehensions :

```
>>> f_list=[map(int,i.split(',')) for i in li]
>>> ['yes' if toa in range(i,j) else 'No' for i,j in f_list]
['yes', 'yes']
```

Fist you need to extract your ranges that it can be done with splitting your strings with `,` and convert to `int` with `map` function.

Then you can use a list comprehension like following to check the member-ship :

```
['yes' if toa in range(i,j) else 'No' for i,j in f_list]
```

But not that `range` will contains the `start` but not `end` if you dont want such things you need to increase your start when you want to create the range :

```
>>> ['yes' if toa in range(i+1,j) else 'No' for i,j in f_list]
['yes', 'No']
```

Comment: The values are not floats, they are *start and end values*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, It seems like this!

Comment: Thanks @kasara actually my real problem i have two lists one is time interval and second is a values whether is available in time interval and if available it should display how many times that value available in time interval sample program like

Comment: @sreeksdevan Welcome, sorry i couldn't get what you mean can you edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @kasara please find my example in quetion

Comment: @sreeksdevan sorry can you add a sample input with expected output?

Comment: @kasara please find input and out put

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse each string into a start and stop value (integers):

```
ranges = ['1,9', '2,10']

for start_stop in ranges:
    start, stop = map(int, start_stop.split(','))
    if toa in range(start, stop):
        print('yes')
```

Instead of creating a new `range()` object you can just use comparison operators:

```
for start_stop in yourlist:
    start, stop = map(int, start_stop.split(','))
    if start <= toa < stop:
        print('yes')
```

This'll be faster as you don't need to create an additional `range()` object.

You probably want to store those integers instead:

```
ranges = [[int(i) for i in start_stop.split(',')] for start_stop in ranges]
```

to not have to parse them each and every time.

If you need to do a lot of these tests, against a large number of intervals, consider using an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data structure instead. In an Interval Tree finding matching ranges (intervals) takes O(log N) time, vs. O(N) for the straight search. So for 10000 ranges to test against, it'll only take 100 steps to find all matches, vs 10000 steps using the straight search used above.